# How to show inline content in lightbox popup?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, lightbox2

Could it possible to show inline content in `lightbox2` popup? Currently I am using:

```
<a id='lbpopup' href='/popupcontent.php' rel='lightframe' style='display:none;'>flyover</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#lbpopup').click();
  });
</script>
```

By using the above code popup is working, but it using an `iframe` to load content from the page `popupcontent.php`

Actually my requirement is :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='popup-content'>My Popup Content</div>
    <a id='lbpopup' href='#'>Click here</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

While click on the link `#lbpopup`, I want to show the content of div `#popup-content` as popup without using iframe. How can I do that?

> I don't want to try any other jQuery popups like fancybox, colorbox etc. I just want to make it with lightbox2 only.

Comment: Have you tried fancybox? It handles inline content well and is also pretty powerful. http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with lightbox2?

Comment: Is this in Drupal or a standalone site?

Comment: i am using the script in my drupal website. But it could not make in a standalone site?

Comment: Lightbox2 doesn't seem to have many features. It would be sorta hacky if you want to get inline content to work. Maybe you can try this http://old.joesong.com/2010/02/showing-in-page-and-inline-content-in-lightbox2/

Comment: Hi @Pjack, Thanks for the link. That was what I want. Thank you verymuch.

Comment: Ok I'll put an answer so it doesn't show unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lightbox2 doesn't seem to have many features. It would be sorta hacky if you want to get inline content to work. Maybe you can try this

https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20151110065936/http://old.joesong.com:80/2010/02/showing-in-page-and-inline-content-in-lightbox2/

Comment: the above link is broken

Comment: @SanjeevK added archive link